# CefSharp TouchInput on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, touch, cefsharp, windows-7-embedded

I have my application installed on a Windows 7 Pos Ready computer and I've issues with the touch input. It just doesn't work and doesn't respond to any touches. If try to click things with my mouse everything is fine.

The CefSharp version I'm using is v79.1.360 and I use Windows Forms.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done already?

Comment: In my experience, this is typically a device driver issue.  Look at the Human Interface Devices and Mice and Other Pointing Devices in the Device Manager.  Compare your current system with a working system, to determine which devices are missing.  Once you know this, try to determine why they didn't load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your inputs.

I figured it out, basically the previous dev was using CefSharp Forms in a WPF project. I exchanged the implementation with CefSharp WPF and it started to work just nicely.

Comment: 79.1.x is the first release to have WPF touch support. Using the WinForms version hosted in WPF using a WindowsFormsHost was previously the one non experimental option for touch support in WPF.